# Iconos de FontAwesome en Nativescript Vue no aparecen

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Seguí [este tutorial](https://github.com/emiliogrv/nativescript-vue-fonticon) para agregar los íconos de FontAwesome a un proyecto de Nativescript con Vue, pero estos no aparecen hasta que hago un cambio en el código fuente, guardo los cambios y se refresca la app en el dispositivo. Ya lo he probado en dos dispositivos diferentes, limpié la caché y sigue igual. Sugerencias, ideas

Comment: Hola Aarón, bienvenido. Tengo ya un par de años de trabajar con Nativescript Vue y siempre me he encontrado con ese problema. La solución que yo encontré fue instalar Sidekick Nativescript y crear el proyecto desde ahí; ya tiene configurado FontAwesome

Comment: Gracias Hugo, tu respuesta fue de ayuda, desde allí no tengo problemas al generar el proyecto con los íconos.